# WooCommerce rest api not getting curl response

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, postman, woocommerce-rest-api

When I try to run WooCommerce API in `Postman` it shows me `json` response, but when i try to run it will CURL, it doesn't giving me any response and loading, can anyone please help me what is issue of it ?

```
$header = array(
    'Authorization: Basic Y2tfZmE1NWQ1N2RjNmY1xxxxxx'
    );  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://xxxxx.com//wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo $error_msg; die;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($server_output);
    die;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: comment CURLOPT_HEADER line